# Write/Read Small File

Tags: node.js, file, heroku

I want to save the "state" of my application each time it is changed, and load it each time the application is booted up.
The "state" will be a simple object with a handful of variables in it, the idea is to `JSON.stringify` it to a file, and `JSON.parse` it when needed.

From what I understand, this cannot be done using Node's `fs`, since files on Heroku are not permanent.
I cannot use S3 either, because it's not free (free plan only lasts a year), and this is a hobby project of mine - I am not willing to pay for it.
Another recurring suggestion, is to use some sort of a database, but I think that is a waste of time, since I will only be dealing with one very small file.

Essentially, my question is, how can I achieve something that is closest to this?:

```
WRITE("filename.txt",JSON.stringify(x));
x=JSON.parse(READ("filename.txt"));
```

(P.S: I've read somewhere, can't seem to remember where, that Heroku gives free 100MB (Which would be way more than enough). What is that? Does it have anything to do with my code?)

Comment: It's not problem to use Redis: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/rediscloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a few ways to do this for free. They all pretty much boil down to "*What free service allows me to read/write arbitrary file content,  and access via an API*?"…

- Do you use or already pay for Dropbox (or something similar?). If so you could you the [Dropbox API for Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dropbox) to save/load your application state.
- You could use the [Github Gist API](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/) and just update the same Gist over and over.

Otherwise, you mentioned databases. Sure, a database would be overkill tech-wise, but given your constraints (and the fact that you can get a small db for free on Heroku), and how much overhead implementing one of the aforementioned APIs would be, it might be the best option.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Beautiful and in-depth answer! Thank you! One question though: I already have a free dropbox account, can I use their Node API with that? Or do I need a paid plan for access to the API?

Comment: You'll be able to use the API with a free plan.